# cmudict.dict() vs cmudict.entries() (Python3, NLTK)

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I see two different approaches to accessing information from the Carnegie Mellon Pronouncing Dictionary Corpus Reader (`cmudict`) in `NLTK` (via `Python3`) and am having a hard time understanding the difference between them:

### Version 1

```
from nltk.corpus import cmudict
pro1 = cmudict.entries()
```

### Version 2

```
from nltk.corpus import cmudict
pro2 = cmudict.dict()
```

According to the docs ([here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/cmudict.html)) `cmudict.entries()` returns "the cmudict lexicon as a list of entries containing (word, transcriptions) tuples" whereas `cmudict.dict()` returns "the cmudict lexicon as a dictionary, whose keys are lowercase words and whose values are lists of pronunciations".

However, if the difference between `cmudict.entries()` and `cmudict.dict()` is **only** a difference in returned data type (seems to be what the docs are indicating) why does calling `len()` on the data from each result in two different numbers (example below)?

```
from nltk.corpus import cmudict

pro1 = cmudict.entries()
pro2 = cmudict.dict()

output = ' '.join(["entries length is", str(len(pro1)), "dict length is", str(len(pro2))])
print(output)
```

which returns: `entries length is 133737 dict length is 123455`

Is there something I am misunderstanding about the difference between these two methods? Is `cmudict.enries()` somehow more complete?

Comment: A dict cannot contain duplicate keys.  In cases where there's more than one transcription for a given word, `.entries()` gives you multiple tuples for that word, but `.dict()` gives you a single entry, whose value is a list with multiple transcriptions.  If you summed up the lengths of all the `.dict()` values, you would presumably get the same length as the `.entries()`.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhh okay that makes sense, thanks so much for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

The **cmudict** module returns all of CMUdict in one big dictionary via the `dict()` method, with each word as a key and a list of matching phonetic representations as the key value. The `entries()` method returns a large list of tuples, where each tuple consists of two elements: a word string and a list of one of the word's phonemes. Each tuple only represents a single phonetic representation of the word, so words with multiple phonetic representations have multiple tuple entries.  As a result, the length of `entries()` is greater than the length of `dict()`, since `dict()` only has one entry (key/value pair) per word, and `entries()` may have multiple entries (tuples) per word.

Some exemplary code may help:

```
import cmudict

def lookup_word(word_s):
    return cmudict.dict().get(word_s)        # standard dict access

def lookup2_word(word_s):
    entries = [e[1] for e in cmudict.entries() if e[0] == word_s]
    return entries

def count_syllables(word_s):
    count = 0
    phones = lookup_word(word_s)
    if phones:
        phones0 = phones[0]
        count = len([p for p in phones0 if p[-1].isdigit()])
    return count

word_s = 'hello'
phones = lookup_word(word_s)
phones2 = lookup2_word(word_s)
count = count_syllables(word_s)
print(f"PHONES({word_s!r}) yields {phones}\nCOUNT is {count}")
print(f"PHONES are same: {phones == phones2}")
```

Answer (score 1):

the cmudict lexicon as a list of entries containing (word, transcriptions) tuples so the words with more than one pronunciation have more then one tuple.